# Mapping issue between knockout's ViewModel and MVC's Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, knockout.js, model-binding

This time I faced with a problem of mapping the client side knockout.js' viewModel and the server side MVC's Model.

So the point is:

I have a knockout viewmodel and some methods in it.

For example one of them looks like this:

```
                    this.search = function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Search"))",
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    beforeSend: function () {
                                    },
                                    complete: function () {
                                    },
                                    data: ko.toJSON(this),
                                    cache: false,
                                    contentType: false,
                                    processData: false,
                                    success: function (result) {
                                        alert(result);
                                    }
                                });
                    };
```

The knockout viewModel and the MVC's Model have the same fields, the only difference is the first letter of each field: the knockout 's field start with a small letter and the MVC's Model field start with a Capital letter, for example: someField - SomeField

So in my case I 'm trying to make a post to the server using the mentioned above search method. Before doing it I even check whether the viewModel has the proper data, and I successfully displayed this.startDate()
but when I put the breakpoint on the server side of my Search action I can see that I receive no data...
That's more than strange.

Recently I successfully implemented implemented a project where I used knockout and I did not have this problem.

I even put [Serializable] on top of the sever side Model but no result.

Please advice what could effect on this and how can I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The MVC model binder is case sensitive. Adjust one of the models to match the other, or use KO mappings.

Comment: But if it's case sensitive then how it worked in my previous project? And why MS presentation of knockout was done having someField-SomeField (the video is available on youtube)?

Comment: I'll have to check that out, I've found that the model binder is quite finicky about properly matching case between the POST and the method signature / object signature. Serialization markup attributes would be one way you'd get the mapping done, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's getting more and more weird...

I created the test knockout ViewModel (I'm using several VMs on a page):

```
            var testViewModel = function () {
                this.Name = ko.observable("");

                this.testsearch = function () {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Test"))",
                                type: 'POST',
                                beforeSend: function () {
                                },
                                complete: function () {
                                },
                                data: ko.toJSON(this),
                                cache: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                success: function (result) {
                                    alert(result);
                                }
                            });
                };
            } 

  var testVM = new testViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(testVM, $("#testSection")[0]);
```

This is the HTML section:
        [section   id="testSection" style="background-color: white;"]
           [input data-bind="value: Name" /] 
            [button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: testsearch"]Test[/button]

```
   [/section]
```

This is my Server side Model:
    [Serializable]
    public class TestDataModel
    {

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my action :

```
    public JsonResult Test(TestDataModel vm)
    {
        return Json("");
    }
```

And In my action I receive null...
I'm completely stucked now...

Comment: One more thing: when I debug I can see that the client side sends json with the data. But why the server side action gets null is unclear